# use php variable in multiple files after jquery post

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I am attempting to load a php page (via jquery) into the main section of a website, the php page I am trying to load needs to share a variable from the main page. Here are the lines of code from the main page:

```
<div id="main" role="main">
<? $path=pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);$path="photo_store/".$path['filename']."/*"; ?>
</div>
```

in the head section of this main page a js file is called which only posts the second php file, the code in the js file is:

```
$(function() {$.post("images.php",function(data){$('#main').html(data);});});
```

The second of the php files is used to create and display an array of images from photo_store sub directory with the following code

```
$files = glob($path);
```

I have looked into the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` but am not entirely sure how they function and have not been successful with them. Obviously if I manually put the folder location into the `glob()` then it will load perfectly same goes if I were to discard the js file and use `include''`, but I really want to find a way so I can use 1 image file for all the folders without using the `include''` option.

Comment: In your code, `$path` is defined twice. Is that intended?

Comment: yes that is intended as the second $path should supersede the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tou must understand that the `images.php` is executed **before it is loaded by AJAX!** This means, you must send the variables using AJAX, to the website, or you have to process it using javascript. (You don't want to do the second thing)
Sending ajax POST parameters - will appear in `$_POST`:

```
$.post(   "images.php",
          {path: "<?php echo $path;?>"},
          function(data){$('#main').html(data);});
```

So, in the `images.php` you can access the `$path` like this:

```
$path = $_POST["path"];
```

Keep in mind, that the user CAN fake the `$path` when it is sent by ajax. He can dispatch his own POST request!

Comment: Thanks for this, I have changed the code to your suggestion but it still is not loading anything, even when i reduce it to the following:

Comment: I'm not a mage - I cannot see in your head, neither can I see into your code. You had, obviously, misunderstood my reply and/or made some mistake in its implementation. That is all I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have changed the code to your suggestion but it still is not loading anything, even when i reduce it to the following: `function loadXMLDoc() {$.post("images.php",{path: "<?php echo $path;?>"},function(data){$('#main').html(data);});}` and then this in the images.php file `$path = $_POST["path"];echo '<h1>'.$path.'</h1>';?>`

Comment: One thing to note - `<?=$path?>` (I used short tag here) must be **in PHP** file. If you have the javascript code above in `.js` you'll send `"<?php echo $path;?>"` instead of `$path` value. If the AJAX is not loading at all, you have some problem totally unrelated to code I shared. Much like PHP syntax error.

Comment: Thanks again, it must be an unrelated problem as the `echo` pulls the correct path. I think is a little above my competency at the moment. I shall return to using the `include''` option and do a little more leaning.

Comment: Indeed, using AJAX without truly understanding its purpose and mechanisms would lead you in producing very unefective applications. But make sure to install **Firebug** for firefox (and relevant tools, if you use other browsers) as it will make AJAX devlopment way way easyer!